# How to segue to different view controllers with the same "didSelectItemAt"

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am currently working with a tableviewcontroller that has two different tableviewcells and inside each the two different cells there is a collectionview set up. I want to be able for the user to select a collectionview cell inside the first tableviewcell and take them to viewcontroller1 (just an example) and also allow them to select a collectionview from the second tableview cell and take them to collectionview2. I tried writing a portion of code, but when I click on the collectionviewcell inside of the first tavbleviewcell, it tries to segue to the viewcontroller associated with the second tableviewcell.

Here is the test code I wrote:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if currentIndexSection == 0 {

            let vc1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GenreHeaderViewTableViewController") as? GenreHeaderViewTableViewController

            self.present(vc1!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HeaderViewTableViewController") as? HeaderViewTableViewController
        vc?.song = songs[indexPath.row]
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Comment: put a print statement `print(currentIndexSection)`
and see what value you get, is it zero or anything else?

Comment: @MumtazHussain Yes it prints a 0 for currentIndexSection when the first section is clicked on

Comment: @MumtazHussain typo on my side it prints a zero

Comment: Have you checked by putting breakpoints inside both the conditions? Which breakpoint is being hit?

Comment: I added breakpoint first on `self.present(vc1!, animated: true, completion: nil)` and it didn't hit, then I put a breakpoint on `self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)` which hit that breakpoint

Comment: how is your currentIndexSection changing? Can you share the logic of currentIndexSection?

Comment: @MumtazHussain  so my currenIndexSection is set up like this `var currentIndexSection = 0` from there like I said I have two tableviewcells which are setup like this `if indexPath.section == 0 { //code for cell, currentIndexSection = indexPath.section} else { //code for second cell, currentIndexSection = indexPath.section }` the currentIndexPath is suppose to be equal to the indexPath.section of the tableview cell

Comment: So, this logic is implemented inside which tableview event? cellForRowAt? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @MumtazHussain the logic above is housed inside cellForRowAt, that is correct

Comment: Have you tried to move the line <currentIndexSection = indexPath.section> to the table view delegate method didSelectRowAt. And if that does not work try changing it to <currentIndexSection = indexPath.row>  because maybe you do not have 2 sections, and you just have two cells.

Comment: @NicolasElPapu I have tried both solutions and they did not work, they made the app crash as soon as they loaded.

Comment: @MumtazHussain I am now running the app and now it is hitting the breakpoint at this line of code: `self.present(vc1!, animated: true, completion: nil)`